# Scalability of the PyQt application

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm new to PyQt. I created a timer, but I need the application with all widgets to scale to different screens. I guess there are a lot of jambs and mistakes in terms of writing code, but it works). I will accept criticism and advice and take it into account.

In general, help to make the application to be scaled for different screens

I attached the code, thank you in advance

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
import time
from termcolor import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__()

    self.setWindowTitle("Таймер")
    self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080)

    #кнопка старта
    self.btn_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
    self.btn_start.move(50, 40)
    self.btn_start.setText("Старт")
    self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.start_timer)

    #кнопка сброса
    self.btn_reset = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
    self.btn_reset.move(50, 200)
    self.btn_reset.setText("Сброс")
    self.btn_reset.clicked.connect(self.reset)

    #место ввода
    self.input_text = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
    self.input_text.move(50, 80)
    self.input_text.setText("15")
    self.input_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.input_text.toPlainText()

    #место вывода времени
    self.timer1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
    self.timer1.move(200, 50)
    self.timer1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.timer1.setFixedWidth(1500)
    self.timer1.setFixedHeight(900)
    self.timer1.setFont(QFont("Arial", 300))
    self.timer1.setStyleSheet("background-color : #c50c50c50")



    #галочка звука
    self.audio = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self)
    self.audio.move(55, 140)
    self.audio.setText("Включить звук")



    self.blink = False

    #таймер, благодаря которому все работает
    self.timer = QTimer(self)                            
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)                   
    self.timer.setInterval(1000)
    self.time = 0


#функция кнопки старта
def start_timer(self):
    text1 = str(self.input_text.toPlainText())

    try:
        text2 = float(text1)
    except ValueError:
        text2 = 0
        self.input_text.setText("0")
        self.btn_start.setText("Старт")
        self.input_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        
    text3 = float(text2)
    text = text3 * 60

    if self.btn_start.text() == "Старт":
        if not self.time: self.time = text
        self.timer.start()
        self.btn_start.setText("Стоп")
    else:
        self.timer.stop()
        self.btn_start.setText("Старт")


#ГЛАВНАЯ ФУНКЦИЯ, благодаря ей таймер и работает
def showTime(self):

        if self.time > 0:
            self.time -= 1
            text1 = self.time

            #превращение в MM:SS
            ty_res = time.gmtime(text1)
            res = time.strftime("%M:%S",ty_res)
            self.timer1.setText(res)

            if self.time < 61:
                self.timer1.setStyleSheet("color: #FF0000")
            
            if self.time < 30:
                if self.blink == False:
                    self.timer1.hide()
                    self.blink = True
                else:
                    self.timer1.show()
                    self.blink = False


            if self.time == 0:
                self.timer1.setText("00:00")
                self.btn_start.setText("Старт")
                if self.audio.checkState():
                    QSound.play('C:\\Users\\artgr\\OneDrive\\gam1\\pisc.wav')


#функция кнопки сброса
def reset(self):
    self.timer.stop()       
    self.btn_start.setText("Старт")
    self.time = 00.00
    self.timer1.setText(str(self.time))
    self.timer1.setStyleSheet("color: #000000")


def application():
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
application()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)

Comment: I read it, thank you, but I have been searching for an answer, help, etc. to my question/problem for a long time

Comment: You need to use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), as fixed geometries (position and size) are always discouraged. Do some research on the topic as there are dozens of posts and tutorials about them. Also consider using Qt Designer to better understand their usage, even if you still want to create everything by code.

Comment: I tried using layout managers, but I didn't find any information on how to change their size and position in the window